# Have problems with email after DNS switch

Tags: dns, email, godaddy

We switched our website to a new site and hosting platform. We have the basic site URL moved over and the email is working fine.  However, we have a another domain name (thesitename.com) that was hosted by hostgator and the URL was with GoDaddy. We moved the DNS over to GoDaddy and then set up a redirect to the URL.

We are having issues with our Google email now for thesitename.com. We have TXT records for SPF, DMARC, and DKIM set up in GoDaddy, but we are getting a DNS record not found message from MX toolbox.

What are we missing in this?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. You could try to improve it (a lot).

Comment: Did you find hostgator's DNS service not exciting enough? You seem to be struggling to describe the issue let alone test it. You didn't tell us how you tested it. You didn't tell us what the DNS settings were. You didn't tell us *HOW* you moved it. You didn't tell us what the domain was so we could see for outselves what state it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure correct MX records are set up in GoDaddy for thesitename.com. Confirm MX record points to Google's mail servers. Double-check DNS settings and update if needed for proper email functionality.